# AWS Secret IAM policy with tag condition no working through RDS Query Editor

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to create an AWS IAM policy that only allows to get an AWS secret value that is tagged with a specific key/value.

The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_iam-permissions.html#iam-contextkeys) states that the `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` IAM action can be used with `secretsmanager:ResourceTag/<tagname>` context.

But I'm struggling to make it work, I tried the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid"      : "xxxx",
    "Effect"   : "Allow",
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:*:*:secret:rds-db-credentials/*",
    "Action"   : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
        "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/my_key": "my_value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it's not working and I'm getting the following error

> User: arn:aws:iam::00000000000:user/me is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:00000000000:secret:rds-db-credentials/cluster-XXXXX/id-xxx

I double checked that my secret has the `my_key` tag with a `my_value` value.

Note that when I'm removing the `Condition` in the policy, the user is authorized to perform `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue`.

I also unsuccessfully tried to use `"Resource": "*"` with [the condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html).

Am I missing something here?

---

**Edit:** The condition is actually working when performing `GetSecretValue` via AWS CLI or AWS Console. But! The condition blocks when retrieving the secret via [**RDS Query Editor**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/query-editor.html)! Removing the condition make it works instantly, so no other action than `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` is missing. What can possibly make the condition to fail in this particular context?

Comment: One thing to watch out for when testing is that IAM policy changes can take a short while to propagate fully (it's a distributed, eventually-consistent system), so you have to be careful that you are not testing against the previous version of the policy. It's probably worth waiting a minute or two between policy change and subsequent testing.

Comment: This seems to work for me. I set up an IAM user with this policy and I was able to use the awscli to retrieve secrets with a tag of my_key=my_value but I was rejected when I tried other, untagged secrets.

Comment: Hum thank you but it's not working for me even after waiting. Do you tried with `Resource: "*"` or with a partial ARN? Also when I'm removing `Condition` from the policy, the change is made instantly and associated users are able to perform `GetSecretValue` within seconds

Comment: I don't know if that can have any impact but I'm actually using a managed policy (associated to a user) and testing it through RDS Query Editor in AWS Console.. But anyway when I'm removing the condition everything works instantly.. hum..

Comment: I tested with exactly the same ARN as you have. All my tests were with the awscli, simply getting secrets, rather than with RDS directly.

Comment: Yeah, me too.. I get this answer on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/cppwx9/aws_secret_iam_policy_with_tag_condition_no/ewrktdh/

Comment: Not sure what that Reddit  poster is referring to. The AWS console doesn’t have some magic way to get around IAM policies. It’s just API calls made with a set of IAM credentials and evaluated against a set of policies.

Comment: At this point you should open a support case with AWS support.

Comment: @JoeB I got a response from the AWS Premium Support and apparently this behavior is currently not supported by design. That's super strange because I was thinking that the AWS Console was using the exact same API as the public one I'm using..